# Return place in list on button press

Tags: c#, json, list, button, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a collection of buttons based on the contents of a list I have in my program. I'm filling my list from a JSON file I'm parsing in and creating the buttons like so:

```
foreach(string ss in prop1)
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 100+w, 100, 100), prop1[count].ToString()))
    {
        SelectType();
    }

}
```

The list `prop1` contains the values from the first set of keys in my JSON. Where in my program it returns and displays two buttons with the text `Foo` and `Boo`

When I click on `Foo` I need to be able to return that name so I can pass it into a check like so:

```
public void SelectType()
{

    if (obj["building"].Value == "Foo") 
    { 
        GameObject sceneObject = GameObject.Find("#" + key);
        sceneObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
}
```

Where as opposed to hardcoding in `Foo` I pass in another paramenter based on the button click. However, I've no idea how to grab the name out of the list when I press it. Could someone please point me in the right direction and help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
foreach(string ss in prop1)
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 100+w, 100, 100), prop1[count].ToString()))
    {
        SelectType(ss);
    }

}

public void SelectType(string type)
{

    if (obj["building"].Value == type) 
    { 
        GameObject sceneObject = GameObject.Find("#" + key);
        sceneObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've spent hours trying to work that out. thank you.